# Error when unpickling pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pickle

I am running this code on the server:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(25,4))
pickled=pickle.dumps(df)
print repr(pickled)
```

And this code on the client that reads the server's standard output

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pickled=eval(read_from_server())
df=pickle.loads(pickled)
```

And for some reason, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_new_Index'
```

Any ideas how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: What is happening here `pickled=eval(read_from_server())`?

Comment: `read_from_server` reads the standard output from the server via ssh

Comment: And you have already checked that `repr(pickled)` and `read_from_server()`  have the same output?

Comment: It was a pandas version difference, I solved the problem with the `.to_dict()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The solution I implemented, is kind of a hack.*

Every `DataFrame` is converted to a `dict` before sending it to the client, and every `dict` that has the same number of items in each key is assumed to originated from a `DataFrame`.

This method works even if the client and server have different versions of `pandas` installed.

### On the server side:

```
if type(ret)==pd.DataFrame:
    ret=ret.to_dict()
pickled=pickle.dumps(ret)
send_to_client(repr(pickled))
```

### On the client side:

```
    pickled=eval(read_from_server())
    ret=pickle.loads(pickled)
    if (type(ret)==dict):
        #if all the dictionary keys have the same number of records:
        if len(set([len(ret[k]) for k in ret.keys()]))==1:
            ret=pd.DataFrame(ret)
```